# Story where group of people use newspaper clippings to find out happenings of divine intervention

Tags: story-identification, novel

As the title reads, I'm looking for a novel written in the past decade that deals with a group of folks going through newspaper clippings looking for those that deal with divine intervention. I remember the main protagonists were older (40-80). And the main protagonist HATED to be touched by another person. The cover of my copy had a big red spiral image covering the book.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly this could be [*Good Omens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Omens) by Terry Pratchett and Neil Gaiman.

It has had several covers in various editions but [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Goodomenscover.jpg) features an image which, while not a spiral, is roughly circular and has red as a dominant colour.

There are two characters who spend a lot of time going through newspaper clippings, although they are looking for evidence of witchcraft rather than divine intervention. They are the last members of the Witchfinder army, the elderly Witchfinder Sergeant Shadwell and his bemused recruit Witchfinder Private Newton Pulsifer, who answered an ad in the paper under the impression that it was for the Territorial Army and then stayed on out of horrified fascination.

> Newt wasn't deaf. And he did have his own scissors.
>
> He also had a huge pile of newspapers.
>
> If he had known that army life consisted chiefly of applying the one
>   to the other, he used to muse, he would never have joined.
>
> Witchfinder Sergeant Shadwell had made him a list, which was taped to
>   the wall in Shadwell's tiny crowded flat situated over Rajit's
>   Newsagents and Video Rental. The list read:
>
> *1) Witches.*
>
> *2) Unexplainable Phenomenons. Phenomenatrices. Phenomenice. Things, ye
>   ken well know what I mean.*

I can't recall whether it says Shadwell hated being touched specifically, but it sounds in character:

> But he [Newton] found he rather like Shadwell. People often did, much to
>   Shadwell's annoyance. The Rajits liked him because he always
>   eventually paid his rent and didn't cause any trouble, and was racist
>   in such a glowering undirected way that it was quite inoffensive; it
>   was simply that Shadwell hated everyone in the world, regardless of
>   caste, colour or creed, and wasn't going to make any exceptions for
>   anyone.

There are some things that make me less confident that *Good Omens* is the book you are looking for. It was first published in 1990, not this decade. Although Shadwell is quite old, Newton is in his twenties. Your question does not mention comedy, which *Good Omens* definitely is, although it is also has quite a lot of pathos and drama.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me, given how memory can warp things.